# Alignment fail when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, resize

I can't seem to find what's wrong. I've got these 3 images and when I open the browser they are in the right place. But if I resize the browser they get all crazy. If I refresh the page it looks ok again. But if I open a bigger browser and make it smaller it crashes.  I don't understand because the browser size is the same when I refresh..

How can I fix this? Anyone knows what is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<section class="bordo">
        <div class="abt3">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1482686551971696.1073741836.1450873611819657&type=3" target="_blank"><img src="fb.png" onmouseover="this.src='fbgrey.png'" onmouseout="this.src='fb.png'" width="10%" id="face"></a>

            <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/105943617@N06/" target="_blank"><img src="flik.png" onmouseover="this.src='flikgrey.png'" onmouseout="this.src='flik.png'" width="10%" id="flikr"></a>

            <a href="https://500px.com/owlyac" target="_blank"><img src="500.png" onmouseover="this.src='500grey.png'" onmouseout="this.src='500.png'" width="10%" id="gram"></a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And the css:

```
#face {
padding-left: 30%;
padding-right: 2.5%; 
}

#flikr {
padding-right: 2.5%;
padding-left: 2.5%;
}

#gram {
padding-right: 25%;
padding-left: 2.5%;
}
```

You can check it here to see what I mean: http://owly.pt/where.html
Try resizing it to the min size possible to see what I mean.

Thank you!

[image: wrong]
[image: right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div that contains the icons needs to have a % width.

Secondly you should give the images position: absolute. If first point does not work

It looks good - nice design

Looks correct when looking on the I-phone. Which is what I'm using hence the lack of code!

To be clearer on point 1 wrap your 3 images in a div and set that to a % width of your choosing. If behavior continues add position absolute to you container and icons.

The reason I ask about bootstrap is that you can handle this behavior with media queries.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Thank you!! Tried that but still gives me the same error :(
No, I'm not using bootstrap.

Comment: Has your body got 100% min width set?

Comment: I ask because when using % attributes it could something very simple like an unrelated div having px etc

Comment: Thank you. It still doesn't work. But yeah it looks ok on mobile...it just happens when I resize the browser. It's really frustrating ._. meh.

Comment: You appear to be positioning using padding. Try position :absolute and set positions without padding. Position:absolute. Left:30% etc

Comment: It worked! I changed the paddings to margins and the fail is gone :) Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Nice site

Answer (score 1):

I think you are messing with all these % in (padding & width) of your icons and "abt3" div. You can remove all padding from #face, #flick, #gram, your div "abt3" has text-align:center, so it will do the centering thing. You can use margin-right:10px to keep spaces between icons

```css
#face, #flick{
  margin-right:10px
  }
```